# SonarQube jenkins plugin returns "Server returned HTTP response code: -1, message: 'null' for URL: https://api.github.com/user"

Tags: github, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube-scan

I'm getting the following response while trying to run sonar-scanner from Jenkins per pull request -

> org.sonar.plugins.github.PullRequestProjectBuilder: Unable to
>   perform GitHub WS operation: Server returned HTTP response code: -1,
>   message: 'null' for URL: https://api.github.com/user -> [Help 1]

I'm working internal organization network, but I've configured the proxy on Jenkins, maven, git. My SonarQube runs on different server than the Jenkins node executing the build.

If I'm trying the sonar scan on the Jenkins build without trying to use the GitHub option - it runs smoothly. Moreover all other tools reach github perfectly, pullrequestbuilder(jenkins)  even updates the status automatically (so it seems a strictly sonarqube issue).

Thanks ahead.

**Update #1:**

mvn command -

```
mvn -X -e sonar:sonar >> SonarQubeReport.txt \
-Dsonar.host.url=http://XXX:9000/ -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 \
-Dsonar.verbose=true -Dsonar.sources=src\main\java -Dsonar.forceUpdate=true \
-Dsonar.analysis.mode=issues -Dsonar.github.pullRequest=${gphrbPullId} \
-Dsonar.github.user="XXXX" -Dgithub.oauth="XXXXX" \
-Dsonar.github.repository=XXX/XXXX -Dsonar.login=XXXXX
```

Result:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T18:41:47+02:00)
Maven home: C:\maven\3.3.9\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_77, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows server 2012 r2", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"

[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: org.jenkins-ci.plugins:hello-world:hpi:2.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [sonar:sonar]
[DEBUG] Style:   Aggregating
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Hello World Example Plugin 2.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) @ hello-world ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]

[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@53a84ff4
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] User cache: C:\Users\xxxx\.sonar\cache
[DEBUG] Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
[DEBUG] Get bootstrap index...
[DEBUG] Download: http://xxx.xxx.net:9000/batch_bootstrap/index
[DEBUG] Get bootstrap completed
[DEBUG] Create isolated classloader...
[DEBUG] Start temp cleaning...
[DEBUG] Temp cleaning done
[DEBUG] Execution getVersion
[DEBUG] Execution start
[DEBUG] Issues global mode
[INFO] Load global repositories
[DEBUG] GET 200 http://xxx.xxx.net:9000/batch/global | time=93ms
[INFO] Load global repositories (done) | time=315ms
[INFO] User cache: C:\Users\xxx\.sonar\cache
[INFO] Exclude plugins: devcockpit, buildstability, pdfreport, report, scmstats, buildbreaker, views, jira
[INFO] Load plugins index
[DEBUG] GET 200 http://xxx.xxx.net:9000/deploy/plugins/index.txt | time=8ms
[INFO] Load plugins index (done) | time=8ms
[DEBUG] Load plugins
[DEBUG] Load plugins (done) | time=17ms
[DEBUG] API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin C# [csharp] (built with API lower than 5.2)
[DEBUG] API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin Git [scmgit] (built with API lower than 5.2)
[DEBUG] API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin SVN [scmsvn] (built with API lower than 5.2)
[DEBUG] Plugins:
[DEBUG]   * C# 5.3.2 (csharp)
[DEBUG]   * GitHub 1.3 (github)
[DEBUG]   * Java 4.2 (java)
[DEBUG]   * Git 1.2 (scmgit)
[DEBUG]   * SVN 1.3 (scmsvn)
[DEBUG]   * JavaScript 2.14 (javascript)
[DEBUG] Execution getVersion
[INFO] SonarQube version: 6.0
[INFO] Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[DEBUG] Work directory: C:\workspace\xxx\208\target\sonar
[DEBUG] Execution getVersion
[DEBUG] Execution execute
[INFO] Process project properties
[DEBUG] Process project properties (done) | time=6ms
[INFO] Load project repositories
[DEBUG] GET 200 http://xxx.xxx.net:9000/batch/project.protobuf?key=org.jenkins-ci.plugins%3Ahello-world&issues_mode=true | time=31ms
[INFO] Load project repositories (done) | time=213ms
[INFO] Execute project builders
[DEBUG] Unable to perform GitHub WS operation
org.kohsuke.github.HttpException: Server returned HTTP response code: -1, message: 'null' for URL: https://api.github.com/user
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:532) ~[github-api-1.76.jar:na]
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester._to(Requester.java:247) ~[github-api-1.76.jar:na]
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.to(Requester.java:209) ~[github-api-1.76.jar:na]
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.getMyself(GitHub.java:279) ~[github-api-1.76.jar:na]
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.<init>(GitHub.java:145) ~[github-api-1.76.jar:na]
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHubBuilder.build(GitHubBuilder.java:196) ~[github-api-1.76.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.github.PullRequestFacade.init(PullRequestFacade.java:80) ~[sonar-github-plugin-1.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.github.PullRequestProjectBuilder.build(PullRequestProjectBuilder.java:52) [sonar-github-plugin-1.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectBuildersExecutor.execute(ProjectBuildersExecutor.java:53) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ImmutableProjectReactorProvider.provide(ImmutableProjectReactorProvider.java:32) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.instantiateComponentAsIsStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1034) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterIfStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1026) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1003) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:141) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:115) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:118) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62) [sonar-scanner-api-batch4396532511294315936.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60) [sonar-scanner-api-2.6.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.execute(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:240) [sonar-scanner-api-2.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151) [sonar-scanner-api-2.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:78) [sonar-maven-plugin-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:112) [sonar-maven-plugin-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134) [maven-core-3.3.9.jar:3.3.9]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207) [maven-core-3.3.9.jar:3.3.9]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153) [maven-core-3.3.9.jar:3.3.9]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145) [maven-core-3.3.9.jar:3.3.9]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116) [maven-core-3.3.9.jar:3.3.9]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80) [maven-core-3.3.9.jar:3.3.9]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51) [maven-core-3.3.9.jar:3.3.9]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128) [maven-core-3.3.9.jar:3.3.9]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307) [maven-core-3.3.9.jar:3.3.9]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193) [maven-core-3.3.9.jar:3.3.9]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106) [maven-core-3.3.9.jar:3.3.9]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863) [maven-embedder-3.3.9.jar:3.3.9]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288) [maven-embedder-3.3.9.jar:3.3.9]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199) [maven-embedder-3.3.9.jar:3.3.9]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: access_denied
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:510) ~[github-api-1.76.jar:na]
    ... 80 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.603 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-14T10:29:09+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 78M/382M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project hello-world: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.ImmutableProjectReactor: Failed to execute project builder: org.sonar.plugins.github.PullRequestProjectBuilder: Unable to perform GitHub WS operation: Server returned HTTP response code: -1, message: 'null' for URL: https://api.github.com/user -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project hello-world: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.ImmutableProjectReactor
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.ImmutableProjectReactor
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:36)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:81)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.ImmutableProjectReactor
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.instantiateComponentAsIsStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1034)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterIfStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1026)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1003)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:141)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:115)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:118)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:240)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:78)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: Failed to execute project builder: org.sonar.plugins.github.PullRequestProjectBuilder
Caused by: Unable to perform GitHub WS operation: Server returned HTTP response code: -1, message: 'null' for URL: https://api.github.com/user
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**Update #3:**
I've ran a manual test using cURL to try to reach GitHub with same token and all, and it seems that for some reason the sonar github plugin doesn't use the proxy configuration defined at the SonarQube configuration file (I will look at the code later).

Command:

```
curl -x http://<proxy address>:8080 -u <github user>:<personal token> https://api.github.com/users/<github user> -I
```

Result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Thu, 15 Sep 2016 06:51:06 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1201
Status: 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4966
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1473922618
Cache-Control: private, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
Vary: Accept, Authorization, Cookie, X-GitHub-OTP
ETag: "xxx"
Last-Modified: Sun, 11 Sep 2016 06:21:00 GMT
X-OAuth-Scopes: admin:repo_hook, notifications, repo
X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: 
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.v3
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Served-By: 8dd185e423974a7e13abbbe6e060031e
X-GitHub-Request-Id: D4758807:3394:7FFB04:57DA44D9
```

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from GitHub: "Unable to perform GitHub WS operation"

Double check your `sonar.github.oath` configuration to make sure you've properly configured an access token with `public_repo` scope.

Comment: Thanks, I checked it and gives the same error even after renewing the token.I've also checked the scope and gave it full permissions to try to make it work. Moreover, on github.com - it writes that the current OAUTH wasn't never used. Just to make sure i should add the token with -Dsonar.github.oauth="" argument right?

Comment: If you think you've used the token but GitHub thinks you haven't, then it's misconfigured.

Comment: I agree that it looked like that, but i've followed all the instructions. I've rechecked it again and again an it still fails on the same issue ... can there be any https / ssl issue? in debug mode it also writes "ssl handshake failed" ...

Comment: Perhaps you should [edit] your question to expand on that.

Comment: You're right, i updated the log. I tried to test the issue with trying to log from the sonarQube server VM with curl to GitHub and i got an error that reminds this issue while not using proxy. Afterwards, I've checked the proxy settings of SonarQube, Sonar Scanner. It seems that there are no issues in the sonarQube server with proxy since it shows all available plugin. Is there any other place i should check?

Comment: I've Checked the code - it seems that the call to GitHub from the GitHub plugin doesn't use the proxy configured on the SonarQube server. If my fix works, I will issue a pull request next week. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem. Our GitHub Enterprise works with a self signed certificate. So I had to import the Certificate into my Java-Keystore for the JVM my gradle Process runs with.

Answer (score 0):

Issue have probably occurred due to proxy support issues, fix details is in the following pull request:
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-github/pull/20

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, but in my case, it was not a proxy issue since all my servers (sonar/github/jenkis) are behind the firewall.

I ended up using [keineantwort](https://stackoverflow.com/users/517518/keineantwort) solution.

I'm just extending the answer for the people looking for the commands to do it.

1. Download the certificate

   `openssl s_client -connect github.MYDOMAIN:443 < /dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > public.crt`
2. Import the certificate

   `<JAVA_HOME>/bin/keytool -import -alias github.MYDOMAIN -keystore <JAVA_HOME>/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file public.crt`

Where github.MYDOMAIN is the fqdn of my github enterprise instance